# TSQL querying xml with namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I've been searching for a solution to my problem. Actually I want to retrieve some data from an XML column.
Here are the data:

```
<Notification xmlns="http://model.company/notification/de/v1" 
    dateNotification="2017-07-24T11:47:51.012+02:00" 
    identifiant="4b7330c7-021f-4cf9-ace6-f74d73f409ef" 
    personneId="1071249" 
    source="REGLES" 
    sourceVersion="1.0.17" 
    typeMouvement="MODIFICATION">
        <EvenementDE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            referenceOriginale="1071249" 
            xsi:type="ChangementSignaletique">
                <Champ 
                    ancienneValeur="Doe" 
                    nom="nom" 
                    nouvelleValeur="DOE" />
        </EvenementDE>
        <EvenementDE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            referenceOriginale="1071249" 
            xsi:type="ChangementSignaletique">
                <Champ 
                    ancienneValeur="John" 
                    nom="prenom" 
                    nouvelleValeur="John Carl" />
        </EvenementDE>
</Notification>
```

I'd like to retrieve the "ancienneValeur", "nouvelleValeur" for a specific "referenceOriginale".
Here's the fiddler: [Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d2be9/1/0)
Getting an attribute from the root is easy, but can't get attributes from Champ.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the proper [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) for the elements and attributes you wish to query/present.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'... your xml...';    

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://model.company/notification/de/v1')  
SELECT 
    N.N.value('./Champ[1]/@ancienneValeur', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [ancienneValeur]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Notification/EvenementDE') As N(N) 
WHERE N.N.value('./@referenceOriginale', 'INT') = 1071249
```

... results ...

```
ancienneValeur
Doe
John
```

Comment: Especially with larger XMLs it would be better to include the `WHERE` as *predicate* into the `.nodes()`'s `XQuery`. Something like `.nodes('/Notification/EvenementDE[@ReferenceOriginale=1071249]')`. If needed, one might introduce the hardcoded value with `sql:variable()` or with `sql:column()`.

Comment: Good point.  The `.exist(...)` function is also faster than `.value(...)` and `.query(...)`